# Cache or store in session?

Tags: php

I have a page that has quite a lot of data loading from my db. I'd like to speed-up loading time. I already cache query, but still the loading time is longer than I'd like it to be.

Is it possible to render a table with data and store it in a session to load on every new page refresh? I was even thinking of putting it in an external text file using ob_start();

What's the best way to handle it?

Comment: What have you done to identify where the bottleneck is? Any profiling?

Comment: Why didn't you just start by trying to make your **queries faster** to not bother with caching at all?

Comment: @Louis-Philippe Huberdeau What tool would you recommend for profiling?

Comment: use EXPLAIN - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html or to profile your code you could use XDEBUG (http://xdebug.org/)

Comment: @zerkms It's a data intensive application with the data presented in a number of ways, including raw numbers, percentages, multi-dimentional sort and a plotted on a graph. The queries are as optimized as they could.

Comment: @santa: if so - I'm wondered you ask such questions then

Comment: Profiling with xdebug will allow you to see where time is consumed in your application. Most of the time, I find that my assumptions are wrong. You may just be trying to cache something with low impact. As for queries optimized as they could, did you run each of them through EXPLAIN to make sure they were using the indexes you thought they were?

Answer (score 5):

Storing it in sessions is probably not the best idea, when you add data to a session (by default) the data is written to a file on the OS, usually in /tmp/ which means you're going to be hitting the disk quite a lot and storing just as much data.

If the data is not user specific then you could store it on disk, or in memory - (see: php.net/apc)

If the data is user specific, I recommend storing it in a distributed cache, such as Memcached  (memcached.org) PHP has a library you can enable (php.net/memcached)

(by user specific I mean data like a users transactions, items, shopping cart, etc)

The logic is basically the same for any method you choose:

Memcached, user specific data example:

```
<?php

$memcached = new Memcached();
$data = $memcached->get('shopping-cart_' . $user_id);

if (!$data) {
    $sql = $db->query("..");
    $data = array();
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row;
    } 
    $memcached->set('shopping-cart_' . $user_id, $data);
} 
?>
<table>
<?php 
foreach ($data as $item) {
    echo '<tr><td>' . $item['name'] .' </td></tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

Global data (not user specific)

```
<?php
$cache_file = '/cached/pricing-structure.something';

if (file_exists($cache_file)) {
    echo $cache_file;
} else {
    // heavy query here 
    $h = fopen('/cached/pricing-structure.something', 'w+');
    fwrite($h, $data_from_query);
    fclose($h);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing caching on a single web server (as opposed to multiple distributed servers), [PHP APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) is a very easy-to-use solution.  It is an in-memory cache, similar to memcache, but runs locally.  I would avoid storing any significant amount of data in session.

APC is a PECL extension and can be installed with the command

```
pecl install apc
```

You may need to enable it in your php.ini.